# How to dynamic divider a table (begin in div, end in other div)

Tags: html, css

I have a long table and I want to split them in two.
The begin of table in left div and the end of the table in a right div. 
I success to divide with 2 table

I have do this (exemple with 8 row):

```
<input id="search">
<div class="row">
  <div class=col-lg-6>
    <table id="table-1">
      //4 first row
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class=col-lg-6>
    <table id="table-2">
      //4 end row
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is : When with a search bar I show only the elements who contains the value I have enter. Some row on the left or on the right could be hide BUT if with my search I get 4 rows I want 2  on the left and 2 on the right.

I don't really know how I can do it... 
I hope you can understand what I say... 
Thanks

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you are using tables? Why not use css column-* (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns)

Answer (score 0):

I created a fiddle for you. Please tell me if this is what you meant or not, so I can update the fiddle:

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xa4oe0r1/73/)

Basically I use "float:left" on both table dividers and "position:relative" in the parent div so that both tables end up next to each other

**HTML**

```
<input id="search">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 table-wrapper table-wrapper-1" id="table-wrapper-1">
    <table id="table-1" class="table">
    <tr><td>John Doe</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Maria Thompson</td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 table-wrapper" id="table-wrapper-2">
    <table id="table-2" class="table">
      <tr><td>Carla Thompson</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Camila Thompson</td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.table-wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

#search {
  width: 100%;
}

.table {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Thank your for the time you take but I already did it and the problem is solve with style css -> columns

Comment: @ClémentM, Nice! Glad you found it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. 
**Jeff in comments give me the right one !** 
I made this :

```
<div class="row" >
    <div style="columns:2 auto">
        <table>...</table>                                  
    </div>
</div>
```